# display:table-cell doesn't work properly with 100% width

Tags: html

I wanted to align text vertically inside of `div`:

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Text is getting aligned, but `div` (which has 100% width) becomes smaller in width. What is the problem? Is there any other good way to align vertically?

EDIT: little more HTML code:

```
 <div style="position:absolute;top:40%;left:0%;">
  <div id="posts" style="position:relative;">
    <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;width:100%;height:100px;position:relative;text-indent: 1.5em"></div>
   <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;width:100%;height:100px;position:relative;text-indent: 1.5em"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there `padding` or `cellpadding`?

Comment: can we see your html?

Comment: @PHPglue no, there is not

Comment: The most likely reason is that this div is affected by other elements on the page. Without the html, it is difficult to confirm this.  Can you look at the page source via a browser and copy and paste that to show us what you have?

Comment: `<div id="posts "style="position:relative;">`?

Comment: @PHPglue just inattention. this is right in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your code to get it to work:

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:40%;left:0%;width:100%;">
  <div id="posts "style="position:relative;width:100%;">
    <div style="display:table; width:100%;">
     <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;width:100%;height:100px;position:relative;text-indent: 1.5em;text-align:center;">test

   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What you needed was to add a `div` with `display: table` in and set all the containing elements to `100% width`. Also the `div` you are centring needed a `text-align: center`.

Answer (score 4):

An element displayed as `table-cell` without any parent explicitly displayed as `table` will create its own *shadowy* parent displayed as such (and another in-between set as `table-row`). It's nowhere to be seen in the DOM but it still have an effect.

The default table layout algorithm is `table-layout: auto` and you want `table-layout: fixed`: former layout algorithm will adapt dimensions of cells to your content; latter will respect what the author (you) says for widths. You can test by having very little content in 1 "cell" and then a very long multi-line content.

```
#posts {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

You also should remove or adapt widths on cells: total should be 100% or else it'll be proportional on most browsers (Safari being at risk. Maybe not Saf 8 but 6 at least...)

Comment: This one explains well, and `table-layout: fixed` saved my life lol